# How can I combine the front view and cross-sectional images along the center line of the front view for prediction of 3D images

Tags: 3d

Please help me to make the code for combine the images from the front view (image 1.1 and 1.2, size: 512x512) and cross-sectional images (image 2.1 and 2.2, size:420x560) along the center line of the front view as the mat file By Matlab code for prediction of 3D images.
Thank you so much.

[Image 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gidj.png)

[Image 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THnFs.png)

[Image 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEFKx.png)

[Image 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaI5f.png)

My code:

```
    % Read the image
    imagePath = fullfile(currentFolderPath, sprintf('1.png', imageIndex));
    img = double(imread(imagePath));
    
    % Process the image to generate the slice
    slice = (img(:, :, 1) == 255) +  (img(:, :, 2) == 255) +  (img(:, :, 3) == 255);

    % Read the additional images
    imagePath15mm = fullfile(folderPath15mm, sprintf('%d.tif', imageIndex));
    img15mm = double(imread(imagePath15mm));
       
    % Resize the additional images
    img15mm = imresize(img15mm, [512 512]);
    
    % Rotate the additional images
    img15mm = imrotate(img15mm, rotationAngle, 'bilinear', 'crop');
    
    % Process the additional images
    slice15mm = (img15mm(:, :, 1) == 255) +  (img15mm(:, :, 2) == 255) +  (img15mm(:, :, 3) == 255);

    % Combine the slices
    combinedSlice = slice + slice15mm;
    
    % Store the combined slice in the volumeData
    volumeData(:, :, (folderNumber-1)*111 + imageIndex) = combinedSlice;
```